# Upgrading Symfony from 2.8 to 3.1: "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

Tags: json, symfony, composer-php, symfony-3.1

So I have this blog developped with Symfony 2.8.6. I noticed that Symfony3.1 [<strike>LTS</strike>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37545550/upgrading-symfony-from-2-8-to-3-1-your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-a#comment62581918_37545550) version is available and wish to upgrade. I therefore fixed all the deprecation calls.

I grabbed Symfony3.1's `composer.json` file and tried to run

```
$ composer update
```

However, update fails and I get the following output:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.3.4 requires phpspec/prophecy ^1.3.1 -> satisfiable by phpspec/prophecy[v1.6.0, 1.4.0, v1.3.1, v1.4.1, v1.5.0].
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.3.0 requires phpspec/prophecy ^1.3.1 -> satisfiable by phpspec/prophecy[v1.6.0, 1.4.0, v1.3.1, v1.4.1, v1.5.0].
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.3.1 requires phpspec/prophecy ^1.3.1 -> satisfiable by phpspec/prophecy[v1.6.0, 1.4.0, v1.3.1, v1.4.1, v1.5.0].
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.3.2 requires phpspec/prophecy ^1.3.1 -> satisfiable by phpspec/prophecy[v1.6.0, 1.4.0, v1.3.1, v1.4.1, v1.5.0].
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.3.3 requires phpspec/prophecy ^1.3.1 -> satisfiable by phpspec/prophecy[v1.6.0, 1.4.0, v1.3.1, v1.4.1, v1.5.0].
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.3.4 requires phpspec/prophecy ^1.3.1 -> satisfiable by phpspec/prophecy[v1.6.0, 1.4.0, v1.3.1, v1.4.1, v1.5.0].
    - phpspec/prophecy v1.6.0 requires phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock ~2.0 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.4, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3].
    - phpspec/prophecy 1.4.0 requires phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock ~2.0 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.4, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3].
    - phpspec/prophecy v1.3.1 requires phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock ~2.0 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.4, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3].
    - phpspec/prophecy v1.4.1 requires phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock ~2.0 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.4, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3].
    - phpspec/prophecy v1.5.0 requires phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock ~2.0 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.4, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3].
    - phpspec/prophecy v1.6.0 requires phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock ~2.0 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.4, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3].
    - phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 2.0.0 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v3.1.0].
    - phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 2.0.1 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v3.1.0].
    - phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 2.0.2 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v3.1.0].
    - phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 2.0.3 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v3.1.0].
    - phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 2.0.4 conflicts with symfony/symfony[v3.1.0].
    - symfony/symfony v3.1.0 conflicts with phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[2.0.4].
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.1.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.1.0].
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 5.3.* -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4].
```

Here is my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
        "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": { "Tests\\": "tests/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.1.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.7",
        "knplabs/knp-time-bundle": "^1.6",
        "eko/feedbundle": "^1.2",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "lexik/maintenance-bundle": "dev-master",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "5.3.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin",
        "platform": {
            "php": "5.6.16"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "3.1-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried adding the `--with-dependencies` option when running `composer update` but to no avail.

Does anyone know which package is conflicting?

Comment: Just wanted to point out that 3.1 is NOT a Long Term Release.  There will be releases every six months.  The next LTS will be 3.4 due out in Nov 2017. http://symfony.com/roadmap?version=3.4#checker By all means upgrade but make sure you are upgrading for the right reasons.

Comment: @Cerad: Oh my gosh you are so right! Do you think I should stick to the 2.8 then?

Comment: That of course is entirely up to you and your apps.

Comment: @Cerad: You're right. I think I'll go with 3.0 and update as soon as next releases become available up to the 3.4 (LTS). Thanks to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to [a conflict between Symfony 3.1 and `phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock: <3.0`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18903) (which is required by PHPUnit), this is declared in the `composer.json` file:

```
"conflict": {
    "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "<3.0"
},
```

Source: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/b004243cb31059f9a97c0a1a045c2dbd1a77dee8/composer.json#L92

You have several solutions:

- [Install PHPUnit with the `phpunit.phar`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/6628) and remove it from `composer.json` (the Symfony documentation may be [updated](https://github.com/kix/symfony-docs/commit/57b70bbadb8011c5b90c4068a8af71c33f5a35fe) soon)
- Use a previous version of Symfony: 2.3, 2.8 or 3.0

Comment: Yes! I just saw that! I therefore upgraded to 3.0 waiting for the conflict to be resolved. Thanks!